# Where does "time patrol Goku" come from?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes there is a "time patrol" Goku. Where does he come from? He doesnt come from Dragon Ball Super or Dragon Ball GT. Was he created for the Dragon Ball Heroes videogame or manga or does he come from another Dragon Ball videogame? Where does "time patrol Goku" come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wikipedia and some info i have stumbled upon, he comes from an alternative timeline but is pretty similar to the Goku we all know from the main series, although he is supposed to be much more mature the the original Goku.

On of the major differences is that he has not experienced the SSJB transformation unlike main line Goku. Well you can find a bit more info about his on the official wiki page:
http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku:_Xeno